# Loading images in Java applet AccessControlError

Tags: java, image, applet, appletviewer

I'm writing an applet that has to load images. When I run it through appletviewer everything works fine, so my code should be all set. When I try to open it in any browser though, I get the AccessControlException error saying I don't have read permission. I understand that normally this is because the applet is trying to access files on a client's computer. My .Java, .class, and .html files are in `C:/Java` and the images I need to load are in `C:/Java/Images` so I thought they should be accessible, am I wrong? Is there any way to get my applet to load these images in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet running in a browser doesn't have permission to open a file from the local filesystem.

You'll need to add the images to the jar file, and then use [getClass().getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [getClass().getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to load it.

Edit: [Here is an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#images) showing how to load images in an applet.

Comment: *"You'll need to add the images to the jar file"*  Or the 'home server'.

Comment: Yes, adding them to a server for the applet to communicate with would certainly work, but is probably more than the OP wants to do - and I'm *guessing* that he or she is opening the html file from the file system, not using a server.

Comment: You make it sound hard!  `URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "image42.jpg");` will form an URL to an image in the same directory as the HTML.

Comment: +1 : Obviously, it's been some time since I wrote an applet :-/

Comment: *"some time since I wrote an applet"*  That is something I would be rejoicing.  ;)

Comment: yes I am opening the html file from the file system. I'm just starting out with Java, so I don't know much about what I'm doing, but let me explain what I need to do with the pictures. I'm loading 20 pictures and placing them on buttons. Right now I'm using ImageIcon to do this, but it doesn't seem to like when i try to combing URL with ImageIcon. any other suggestions?

Comment: thanks guys, i'll try adding the pictures to a jar file and loading them from there. i read a little about that and it definitely seems to answer my problem.